# Instantiating a model with a ModelChoiceField

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model in my app that contains only one field - a ModelChoiceField - that I would like to be associated with user profiles (users being able to have multiple choices associated with them). These choices won't change while running, and I will eventually use them to filter the users by their choice. Here's what the two models look like.

```
...
class Choice(models.Model):
    Choice1 = 0
    Choice2 = 1
    Choice3 = 2
    Choices_Available = (
            (Choice1, 'Choice1'),
            (Choice2, 'Choice2'),
            (Choice3, 'Choice3'),
    )
    choice = models.IntegerField(choices=Choices_Available, null=True)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.Choices_Available)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Choices_Available[self.choice]

class Profile(models.Model):
    choice = models.ManyToManyField(Choice)
```

The problem I have is trying to actually select a choice and associate that choice with the user. In the user form that would actually do the selecting, in most examples I have seen, a MultipleChoiceField with the available choice objects filtered:

```
...
class EditProfile(forms.ModelForm):
    choice = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=Choice.objects.all(), widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['choice']
```

That particular setup currently means nothing shows up because there are no Choice objects.

I think I would fix that by creating a choice object for each available choice. Then when a user requests that page with the form, they see the available choices. In the end, all users would be able to be associated with however many choice objects there are (in this example 3), and there would only be that many objects stored in the database minimizing space used.

To do that I need to be able to create Choice objects. My question boils down to: how do I create Choice objects with a choice selected (there currently is only the default **init** method). Also, is this a reasonable way of going about this feature?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering the same thing, I'll tell you what I've found out.
To instantiate an object specifying the choice:

```
Choice.objects.create(choice=0)
```

Of course change the number corresponding to the choice, which can be done programmatically.

Also, I had a mistake in the form. MultipleChoiceField is for choosing from a set of options. ModelChoiceField is very similar, but it takes in a queryset of objects and allows you to chose from those objects. This is the functionality you might want for a many to many field like in my example.